# Roxygen2 multiple functions in one file with some hiden function in the usage (using Roxygen2)

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

I am writing a documentation for several S3 methods for a given class. I'm using @rdname to insert all the methods in a single R help document. So, in my documentation, I have the following:

```
# '@name methodsmyclass
# '@param mypar
summary.myclass <- function () ...

# '@rdname methodsmyclass
print.myclass <- function () ...
```

In the help of R
[appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajphj.png)

However, if someone types '?print.myclass',  I would like  'Help' to present the methods page, which will include all of the methods, even the ones that were hidden.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what the desired result is here. How exactly is what you want different than what you are getting?

Comment: Hi! As it is now, when someone types ?print.myclass, the Help shows the picture of the figure. However, I would like that the part "## S3 mehod for myclass \n print(...)" not to appear in usage. This is because I have several methods and I would like to put them all on a single Help page, but that some of them do not appear in usage (to be more elegant).

Comment: You may be out of luck. The `## S3 method` output is (I think) produced by R. If you look at the produced Rd file, you'll see something like `\method{print}{myclass}(x, ...)`. And if you don't have that in there, R CMD CHECK will probably complain.... I agree it often is distracting.